# AngularJS Message Display On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two questions

1. How to display the initial message and/or upon button click. The current code I have displays the message continuously. I want it to display initially and once users starts pressing other button I want the message "Start guessing" to disappear and only appear after user clicks Start Over button.
2. How to display the correct answer when user clicks on Give up.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Template that uses Bootstrap</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1.0"/> 
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --> 
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
        <body>
            <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <div class="container">

                    <h1>Guessing Game</h1><br>
                    <label>Enter Guess:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" data-ng-model="guess"/><br>
                    <span data-ng-bind="Message"></span>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-ng-click="checkGuess()">Check</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md" data-ng-click="showAnswer()">Give Up</button>

                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-ng-click="startGame()">Start Over</button>
                        </div></div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <div ng-show="deviation<0" class="alert alert-warning">Guess higher</div>
                    <div ng-show="deviation>0" class="alert alert-warning">Guess lower</div>
                    <div ng-show="deviation===0" class="alert alert-success">You got it!</div>
                    </div></div>




                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- jQuery – required for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- All Bootstrap plug-ins file -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Basic AngularJS -->
            <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Your Controller -->
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Angular

```
/*global angular */
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.checkGuess = function () {
        $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;
    };

    $scope.startGame = function () {
        $scope.guess = null;
        $scope.original = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
        $scope.deviation = null;
        $scope.display = false;
        $scope.Message = "Start guessing.";
    };

    $scope.showAnswer = function () {
        $scope.original = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
        $scope.display = true;
    };
    $scope.startGame();

}
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `ng-hide` to hide your element when needed:

```
<span data-ng-bind="Message" ng-hide="hideMessage"></span>
```

In the `checkGuess` and `showAnswer` functions set the `hideMessage` to `true`:

```
$scope.hideMessage = true;
```

In the `startGame` function, set it to `false`:

```
$scope.hideMessage = false;
```

2) In your HTML add a tag:

```
<div ng-show="showOriginal">{{previousOriginal}}</div>
```

And in your `showAnser` and `startGame` function, add:

```
$scope.showOriginal = true;
$scope.previousOriginal = angular.copy($scope.original);
```

And remove of the `showAnswer` function:

```
$scope.original = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1)
```

Finally, in the `startGame` function, set it to false:

```
$scope.showOriginal = false;
```

Comment: Awesome mate ! But there is a problem. Everything seems to work except The answer doesn't disappear when Start Over is clicked. I have to refresh page to hide the answer.

Comment: @FoxMuler I forgot that case. Edited my post, should be ok now.

Comment: not working now. This one also looks confusing. Previous one I understood.

Comment: @FoxMulder be carefull, I also modified the HTML to `<div ng-show="showAnswer">{{previousOriginal}}</div>`

Comment: yep, give up doesn't work. I think you also made a mistake saying set $scope.showAnswer = true in startGame as it will start showing the answer from the beginning. Anyways it's not working and I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: seems to be working now after I changed the variable name as it seems to be conflicting with the name of the function for some weird reason.

Comment: @FoxMulder You're right it could be conflicting. Nice spotting. Please upvote and validate my answer as it helped you to fix your problem.

Comment: I have another query mate. The deviation output is wrong. So suppose generated random number is 800 and if user enters 900 the deviation still outputs "Guess Higher" what could be the problem ?

Comment: You have to invert your calculation `$scope.deviation = $scope.guess - $scope.original;`

Comment: Thanks. Can you also tell me why we are evaluating deviation to 0 and how does it work. This is my last query. Promise

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? Be more precise

Comment: Why we are doing deviation<0 ? How does it work ? Since we actually compare deviation to user input why do comparison with 0 ?

Comment: It's just to simplify things. You could have made something like:
`<div ng-show="guess<original" class="alert alert-warning">Guess higher</div>
                        <div ng-show="guess>original" class="alert alert-warning">Guess lower</div>
                        <div ng-show="guess===original" class="alert alert-success">You got it!</div>`

Comment: I did try that it didn't work. Anyways what I am confused about how 0 means original value here ? Because somehow 0 acts like original value so it knows whether to output guess higher or lower and I am not able to grasp that concept.

Comment: It would really help if you could explain it. Thanks

Comment: Hope you get back to me on this.